# circuit_breaking_exception in kibanaa

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
{
statusCode: 429,
error: "Too Many Requests",
message: "[circuit_breaking_exception] [parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [2047736072/1.9gb], which is larger than the limit of [2040109465/1.8gb], real usage: [2047736072/1.9gb], new bytes reserved: [0/0b], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=854525953/814.9mb, in_flight_requests=0/0b, accounting=79344850/75.6mb], with { bytes_wanted=2047736072 & bytes_limit=2040109465 & durability="PERMANENT" }"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

circuit breakers are used to prevent the elasticsearch process to die and there are various types of circuit breakers and by looking at your logs its clear it's breaking the [parent circuit breaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html#parent-circuit-breaker) and to solve this, either increase the Elasticsearch JVM heap size(recommended) or increase the circuit limit.

Comment: You shouldn't need 1.8 GB in order to hold a single HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

As Elasticsearch Ninja alluded to, this error is generally produced from Elasticsearch, despite Kibana being the one displaying the error. Adjusting the heap size for Elasticsearch should generally resolve this error.

This should be done with the `Xms` and `Xmx` options of the `jvm.options` file for Elasticsearch.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#heap-size-settings

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27902917)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I added a bit more detail on the process for adjusting the Elasticsearch heap size to my answer.

Comment: You shouldn't need 1.8 GB in order to hold a single HTTP request. Increasing the heap limit is just hiding the problem.